# Can we use external system to register and verify users from Community Cloud?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, amazon-aws

I created a custom login page in LWC and controller.

I am trying to implement a passwordless login, using username and live selfie. So for registering the user, I dont need users to give any password. They just need username, FirstName, LastName, Email for the user to be created in System and their selfie data will be registered with `Amazon Rekognition`

When later on logging in, they will just use username and provide a selfie. System would fire an api get the verification done and get them logged in. This would work in other applications made in other languages.

I can do the same using custom controller in salesforce, and redirect the user to home, but I have few questions.

1. How will the session be maintained, if I dont use `Site.login()`?
2. As I am not asking for password and while creating user I also need to give a password, Is it safe to create a password in backend and save it by encrypting it with the faceid returned from api from `Amazon Rekognition`
3. Is it necessary to use `Site.login()` when logging into community?